# How can I create a large message on git merge?

Tags: git

I would like to do a `git merge` to plough the work of one branch back into another.

However, since a lot has been done and I'm going to do a no-fast-forward merge I would like the commit to contain extensive information about what's in the merge.

If I were doing a normal commit I could use the `-m` flag and an editor would be fired up for me to put the details into (*edit this is incorrect - see below*). However if I use the `-m` flag during commit it simply tells me that the message requires content:

```
$ git merge development --no-ff -m
error: switch `m' requires a value
```

Since I have a fairly large merge message, I would prefer an editor rather than a single line string. How can I get that though?

**EDIT**

Although the answers have covered my question I realised that using the `-m` flag during a normal commit does not in fact fire up the editor (although `-a` does if you're creating a tag). The only way I've to get the editor during a normal commit it to simply type `commit` with no other flags or options.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `--no-commit` flag, and then type `git commit` - you'll be able to edit the message then:

```
git merge development --no-ff --no-commit
git commit
```

Alternatively, if you've already done the merge, you can amend the merge commit to change its message with:

```
git commit --amend
```

Answer (score 5):

Perform the commit as usual and change the commit message afterwards using `git commit --amend`.